# Add inline JavaScript to the head of Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, inline

I'm trying to add BugHerd (an issue tracking tool) to my Magento 2.1 project, which requires I add the following script into the `<head>` tag:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  (function (d, t) {
     var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
     bh.type = 'text/javascript';
     bh.src = 'https://www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey={my api key}';
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
  })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

There are many questions on this topic referencing old Magento versions, but I can't seem to find an updated answer. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can also use the backend of magento 2 website.

Just add the bugherd JS code in Content>Design>Configuration>"Your Current Store"
and just like the picture insert your JS code there and save.

I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: No problem, You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's directory, create this file: `{theme_dir}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` with the following:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="js/bugherd.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Then you put the `bugherd.js` file in `{theme_dir}/web/js/bugherd.js`

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks for your quick response.